# Array inside redux state is undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

here I'm facing a little problem with react - redux .....
**I'm getting state attribute (array) undefined**.... What might be the reason?
Here is my Reducers.js code ..

```
const initialState = {
    cList: [],        //I'm getting this array undefined...
    selectedCatagory: "",
}

export const reducerForCatagoryList = (state = initialState , action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case "CATAGORY_LIST":
            let lis = [...state.cList,action.payload];
            return Object.assign({},state,{ cList: lis });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Actions.js code is:

```
export const catagoryList = (list) => {
    return {
        type: "CATAGORY_LIST",
        payload: list
    }
}
```

And my Component's code is:

```
//This array is just for testing purpose....
const list = [{
    cName: 1,
    heading: "Heading",
    link: ""
    },
    {
      cName: 2,
      heading: "Heading2",
      link: ""
    }]

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log("state is: ",state);
    return {
        cList: state.cList
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        catagoryList: (list) => {
            dispatch(catagoryList(list));
        }        
    }
}
class MainPage extends Component{
    
    render(){
        console.log("Props are: ",this.props)
        return(
            <div id = "Cards-div">
            {this.props.catagoryList(list)}
            {
                createCards(this.props.cList) //I want to send Array inside redux store (cList) to this......
            }
            </div>
          )
    }

}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(MainPage);
```

So, Plz can someone explain me what's going wrong here?

Comment: Code seems good .For development purposes , try adding `redux-logger` or similar middleware for having an easier time debugging.

Comment: ALso , I am not sure why you are calling function inside of return. add it inside of `componentDidMount(){}`

Comment: Ok **thanks**, I'll try that!